# TextView doesn't change with OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: java, android

Simply, I have created a spinner. There is spinner entries and value of entries in my `array.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="select">
        <item>a</item>
        <item>b</item>
        <item>c</item>
    </string-array>

    <integer-array name="selectValues">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </integer-array>

</resources>
```

Also here is the my `linearlayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/selectLayout"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSelect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/select"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sSelect"
        android:layout_width="179dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:entries="@array/select"
        android:prompt="@string/sec"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity I have created `OnItemSelectedListener` and When an item selected by user I want to change the `TextView`. I think there is a problem when using switch.

Here is the activity.

```
public class Select extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    int[] itemValues;
    TextView t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Resources rsc = getResources();
        itemValues = rsc.getIntArray(R.array.selectValues);
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelect);

        setContentView(R.layout.select);

        Spinner form = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sSelect);
        form.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> item, View which, int sort,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(which.getId())
        {
        case R.id.sSelect:
            int value = itemValues[sort];
            t.setText(value);
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

How to fix that?

**EDIT: When I try to remove switch, I'm getting `unfortunately has stopped` error.**

Comment: Have you checked whether the setText method is called? Maybe a simple if statement is easier here (also if you just set the listener for one spinner it shouldn't be necessary to check for the id of the view)

Comment: I'm programming to learn. Also I checked. Also when I remove switch I get unfortunately error.

Comment: What is R.id.sSelect ?

Comment: try it with t.setText(String.valueOf(value)); may be work and set the contentview before the textview

Comment: @JiteshDalsaniya id of spinner.

Answer (score 1):

1. As Spring Breaker said, you need to call `setContentView()` before calling `findViewById()`. If you call `findViewById()` first, it will return null, and you'll get a `NullPointerException` the moment you try to use the `TextView`.
2. In `onItemSelected()`, `which` is not actually a reference to the `Spinner`. It's a reference to a child view of the `Spinner` which holds the specific item the user pressed. You need to switch over the first argument, the `AdapterView<?>`.
3. `setText()` expects either a `String` or an `int` resource value referencing an XML string. You're passing it an `int`, but not a resource value, so it won't work. Here's a quick workaround:

   ```
   String value = String.valueOf(itemValues[position]);
   t.setText(value);
   ```

Comment: By the way, one easy way to debug problems like this is to add "breakpoints" to your code and then click `Debug` in your IDE (instead of `Run`). In your case, adding a breakpoint at the beginning on `onItemSelected()` would show you which of the arguments is the `Spinner`, and that your `TextView` variable is null.

Answer (score 0):

which.getId() returns the id of the item selected within the spinner, not the spinner's ID, R.id.sSelect is the spinner's id

Comment: then how to validate id of spinner?

Answer (score 0):

Do this way..

```
    form.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int sort, long arg3) {
                int value = itemValues[sort];
                t.setText(value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there no way with using implements?

Answer (score 0):

use setcontentview() method  before defining views

i.e. before this line ->
t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelect);

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  `setContentView(R.layout.select);` before referencing any ID from the layout file.In your case, the `onCreate()` should be as follows,

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.select);

            Resources rsc = getResources();
            itemValues = rsc.getIntArray(R.array.selectValues);
            t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelect);                  
            Spinner form = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sSelect);
            form.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
 @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> item, View which, int sort,
                long arg3) {


             String  SpinerValue3 = item.getItemAtPosition(sort).toString();
             t.setText(SpinerValue3);
        }
```

Comment: Really nothing change. I think app doesn't enter inside of switch?

Comment: But you are getting position, what will be if values be string or different things?

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(which.getId())
        {
        case R.id.sSelect:
            t.setText(form.getselecteditem().tostring());
            break;
        }
```

Comment: I think you couldn't understand what i am asking and what I try to do :)

Comment: You are setting int in textview. int value = itemValues[sort];
            t.setText(value); parse **value** into String first

Comment: thats wasn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

try it with t.setText(String.valueOf(value));

may be work and set the contentview before the textview

Answer (score 0):

Change your `switch` statement to below code.

```
        switch(sort)
        {
            case 0:
                int value = itemValues[0];
                t.setText(value);
                break;
            case 1:
                int value = itemValues[1];
                t.setText(value);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, AppFit has stopped :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved this by implementing the listener inline and calling a specific function to handle this. From the debugger I learned that the sent id has nothing to to do with the spinner id